# How to pass JSON data from server to client side and use the data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I would like to pass a JSON from server side to client side in Node.js. On the client side I want to use them in Javascript then.
What I tried so far:

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   let data = {
      "questions":{
         "5-2?":[
             {
               "ans1":"3"
             },
             {
               "ans2":"8"
             },
          ],
          "1+2":[
            {
              "ans1":"3"
            },
            {
              "ans2":"1"
            }
          ]
      }
   };
 res.render('test', { data: data });
});
```

In my pug file I want to use that data with Javscript like this:

```
console.log(!{data});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server you transmit the data using `JSON.stringify()` and on the client you receive the serialized JSON representating the data structure that you stringified. To turn this back in to an object that you can use, use `JSON.parse()`